# wireit: visualizing a directed graph with nodes that can contain nested graphs

Tags: interface, graph, visualization, widget

**Problem:**

There appear to be many tools for visualizing graph structures, but none of the ones I've seen so far seem to have the feature of "nesting". The WireIt library (apparently inspired by Yahoo Pipes) looks very promising, but it seems to lack this concept of nesting.

To explain what I am thinking of, consider a Company Org Chart where each "box" in the Org Chart has a button with three dots [...]

When you click on the button, the chart "drills down" into the sub-organizations within the node you just clicked on, you can use the backspace key (or some other convention) to jump back up to the originating node.

**Question:**

Does anyone know of a GUI toolkit (prefer web-compatible) that includes this concept of nesting? The WireIt library looks promising, but if there are any others out there you are aware of, feel free to include that also.

TIA for any info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two desktop tools I know of support the kind of nesting you're referring to: [NodeXL](https://nodexl.codeplex.com/) and [Cytoscape](http://www.cytoscape.org/). In NodeXL, a network visualization template for Excell 2007--2013, you can define a group manually or using a clustering algorithm, then collapse it into a single node. You can then expand individual groups on demand. Cytoscape has a similar feature, though I'm unfamiliar with the terminology it uses. In the latest version you can even show an image on the group node that shows the underlying subgraph.

Another option is to just separate the groups visually in the drawing. NodeXL includes a new Group-in-a-Box layout that separates groups into their own region of the screen, whether the groups are components, clusters, or manually created. Below are some examples and a reference for the associated paper.

- Rodrigues, E. M.; Milic-Frayling, N.; Smith, M.; Shneiderman, B. & Hansen, D. Group-in-a-Box layout for multi-faceted analysis of communities SocialCom '11: Proc. 2011 IEEE 3rd International Conference on Social Computing, 2011, 354-361. [DOI:10.1109/PASSAT/SocialCom.2011.139](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/PASSAT/SocialCom.2011.139)

[image: NodeXL with the Group-in-a-Box treemap layout]

[image]

[image]

*Disclaimer: I am an advisor and developer on the NodeXL project.*

Answer (score 2):

[Flare](http://flare.prefuse.org/demo) should be able to handle nested nodes.  Look at Layouts -> Circle Pack in the demo.  I believe [Protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/ex/) can also handle nested nodes, though I don't see a demo that shows it off.

Answer (score 1):

The Graphviz library has the ability to do nested clusters.  See this example: http://www.graphviz.org/content/fdpclust

Graphviz doesn't provide the interactive features directly, but provides many tools (like the ability to export SVG or image maps with attached urls and JavaScript events) that you would need to build an interactive app. Also check out some of the items on the "Resources" tab, some of the project like jQuery.Graphviz may provide some of the interactivity you are looking for.